# What font is the GDAX logo?

Tags: font-identification

What font is this, it has a squarish kind of look and gentle curves to not make it look sci-fi yet suitable for corporate use. I know the 'X' character is customized but I am looking for the rest, the 'G' is a little customized as well. I tried to find with WhatTheFont and the font was Allumi Std which was quite far off, it doesn't have the curves at those right places.
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's Prometo Extra Bold, I found it on MyFonts using Font Squirrel Matcherator.

[image]